# jQuery not sending JSON on AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mongodb

I am a little confused here,I am trying to post data to my node js server using the following code:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',
        url:'/map',
        data:'type=line&geometry='+str,
        success:function(msg)
        {
          console.log(msg);
        },
        datatype:'json'     
    });
```

This is the result here:

```
 { type: 'line', geometry: 'b~cqCge{b[mv|q@xnyC' }
```

This is not JSON.I had previously tried to use `contentType` and do this like this:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',
        url:'/map',
        data:{type:'line',geometry:str},
        success:function(msg)
        {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        datatype:'json',
        contentType:"application/json"  
    });
```

Even this sent the data without any change.I have also tried the above method using the data string from the first one.I have also tried setting `processData` to `false` along with the methods in the code blocks.

It is important to me that the data be in `JSON` and use `AJAX` because I am trying to [insert into mongodb from node js using mongojs and it fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230131/inserting-into-mongodb-using-node-js)

Comment: Well I'd wager that `str` is actually an object, as this smells of an attempt to send GeoJSON type data. Lots of responses here, but I would look for something that would produce a JSON string from an object. Just to help weed out the right one. And keep "contentType" there. Your server may not care, but it **should**.

Comment: @NeilLunn str is a String obtained by using `google.maps.Geometry.encodePath` which returns a `String`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually `dataType` has nothing to do with the input but rather the output.

Instead what you want is to stringify your input `data` and then send that down as a single variable to your backend which can then decode it:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',
    url:'/map',
    data: {data: JSON.stringify({type: 'line', geometry: str})},
    success:function(msg)
    {
       console.log(msg);
    },
    dataType:'json'     
});
```

That way in your backend you just decode `data` and it should be now a fully functioning object from JSON.

Note you will need the JSON class for this, JQuery does not include this ability by default: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Is adding `charset:'utf-8` nessecary??

Comment: @user2309862 I never do so I would say no unless it is really needed

Comment: I was at work until 10pm last night trying to figure this out. I was getting an undefined result from my variables on the back end and indeed on the front end my request was sending an object. I'm going in today (on a Saturday) and I'm going to try this solution out to see if it works! I'll upvote it if it does! :)

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same issue, and NodeJS API backend was receiving `Undefined` request.body.

How i was able to solve by calling AJAX as following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: response => console.log(response),
    error: e => console.log(e)
});
```

Please note that I have to mention both `contentType: 'application/json'`, and `dataType: 'json'`. Also, note that `JSON.stringify`-ing was needed on the payload JSON data.

Comment: This is the one that solved my issue so I upvoted it. I had to put it in this very order and include the content-type as it wouldn't work with out it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataType` instead of `datatype`, **note** the `T` is Capital in `Type` like,

```
dataType:'json',
```

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/map',
    data:{type:'line',geometry:str},
    dataType:'json',// use dataType not datatype
    success:function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }     
});
```

Read [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Answer (score 1):

```
Url = "http://example.com";

var postData = $('#selectorid').serialize();

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData+'&FormType=InsertForm',
            url: Url,
            success: function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                //console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error in register form');
            }
            });
```

Post the all value in php.
Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: '/map',
        data: {type:"line",geometry : str},
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Like @Rohan Kumar mentioned, replace `datatype` with `dataType`

Comment: Your code has errors, you missed a `,` after `data:{...}`

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this problem but this code solved my issue:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  type: "POST",
  url: "/admin/get-message-details",
  data: {"messageId":messageId},
  success: function(){

  }
});
```

By the way data from client to server travels in the form of string. So you can prepare & send your data in the structure of JSON.